# jquery autocomplete datasource change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have setup a jquery autocomplete which changes datasource depending on the input on the textbox.

After datasource on the jquery changes, it doesn't fire until press up or down arrow button.

I have used firebug to check the datasource and I can't find anything wrong with it.

Can someone show me how to send up or down arrow key to a control or resolve this in any other way?

Thanks a lot!

edit: I have replaced this with JSON as following but it seems the request comes error alert box

> jQuery(function () {
>               jQuery("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
>                   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>                   dataType: 'json',
>                   mustMatch: false,
>                   limit: 10,
>                   minChars: 2,
>
> ```
>             select: function (event, ui) {
>                 AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
>             }
>             ,
>             source: function (request, response) {
>                 jQuery.ajax({
>                     url: "http://localhost/integration/webservices/PostcodeJSON.asmx/GetPostCodeListJSONfromSuburb",
>                     data: {},
>                     dataType: "json",
>                     type: "POST",
>                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                     dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
>                     success: function (data) {
>                         alert(data);
>                     },
>                     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus,
> ```
>
> errorThrown) {
>                               alert(textStatus);
>                           }
>                       });
>                   }
>               });
>
> ```
>     });
> ```

there is this html input box.

What have I done wrong here? I have confirmed that the web service is working correctly.

edit2 : I have made changes like the following:

> jQuery(function () {
>               jQuery("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
>
> ```
>             minChars: 2,
>
>             select: function (event, ui) {
>                 AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
>             }
>             ,
>             source: function (request, response) {
>                 jQuery.ajax({
>                     url: "http://localhost/integration/webservices/PostcodeJSON.asmx/GetPostCodeListJSONfromSuburb",
>                     data: '{ Suburb: "' +
> ```
>
> jQuery("#autocomplete").val() + '" }',
>                           dataType: "json",
>                           type: "POST",
>                           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                           dataFilter: function (data) { return data.d; },
>                           success: function (data) {
>                               alert(data.d);
>                           },
>                           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus,
>   errorThrown) {
>                               alert(textStatus);
>                           }
>                       });
>                   }
>               });
>
> ```
>     });
> ```

so the alert is working fine. But jquery does not show matched list. How do I do this?

EDIT 2:

I have managed to work out the issue with webservice. How do I set the response so that autocomplete shows the list accordingly? At the moment each item on the list shows me the full list of items.

ie ) if I type in 'ab' and if there are 3 things that matches up then it will show me the same result 3 times on 3 different lines.

I have the jquery setup like the following:

jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({

```
            minChars: 2,

            select: function (event, ui) {
                AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
            }
            ,
            source: function (request, response) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/integration/webservices/PostcodeJSON.asmx/GetPostCodeListJSONfromSuburb",
                    data: '{ Suburb: "' + jQuery("#autocomplete").val() + '" }',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {

                                                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                                        return {
                                                            value: data.d
                                                        }
                                                                                }))


                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Your description makes little to no sense (to me). For example, `After datasource on the jquery changes, it doesn't fire until press up or down arrow button`. What is `datasource on jquery`? What causes it to change? What is `it` that isn't firing? Without sharing code, helping you is about as impossible as helping someone who says "I'm using autocomplete but it's not working, please help".

Comment: i use request on xmlhttpobject to get the list from a page,
so the datasource is just a string array.
if I change the datasource, the autocomplete list does not show.However, when I press up arrow key or down arrow, then the list shows up.
Maybe I should try to use json with custom datasource.

Comment: Still not clear and certainly not reproducable. If you setup a http://jsfiddle.net it will make everyone's life much easier and up the chances of solving your problem

Comment: whoa I did not know there is tool like this. let me set this up and let know you.

Comment: You probably cannot see the result because I haven't set up a public datasource page. So basically I have written the code to detect key press on the textbox, and wait for 1 sec, if there is no change in the text then javascript will use the keyword to search from a page. And I reset the datasource with the result of the search.

Comment: it seems stackoverflow quote encap is not working as I think so I put the code in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlee923/BQGDa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working but one thing I am not sure is that the item becomes just a string array rather than JSON object. I did try to parse each item as a JSON but doesn't seem to work.

Here is the working jquery json with webservice jquery combinations.

jQuery(function () {
            jQuery("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({

```
            minChars: 2,

            select: function (event, ui) {
                AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
            }
            ,
            source: function (request, response) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/integration/webservices/PostcodeJSON.asmx/GetPostCodeListJSONfromSuburb",
                    data: '{ Suburb: "' + jQuery("#autocomplete").val() + '" }',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    minChars: 2,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
                        response($.map(obj, function (item) {
                            var item_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(item);
                            return {
                                value: item[1]


                            }
                        }))


                    },
                    //                        parse: function (data) {
                    //                            var parsed = [];
                    //                            data = data.d;

                    //                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    //                                parsed[parsed.length] = {
                    //                                    data: data[i],
                    //                                    value: data[i].value,
                    //                                    result: data[i].value
                    //                                };
                    //                            }

                    //                            return parsed;
                    //                        },
                    //                        formatItem: function (item) {
                    //                            return item.value;
                    //                        },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        });



    });
```